# link_error is not executed when task fails in chord header

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I created a test case to reproduce the problem I suffer from in more complex workflow. I expect link_error of the chord callback to be executed every time an error occurs in chord header. In provided example chord header is a group, which consists of one chain. However, in my implementation group can contain multiple chains and/or tasks.

My celery version is **3.1.23**.

test.py:

```
from celery import Celery, chain, group, chord

app = Celery('test', backend='redis', broker='redis://localhost')

@app.task
def task1():
    print("Task 1 executed")

@app.task
def error_task():
    raise Exception("Mocked exception")

@app.task
def callback_task():
    print("Callback executed")


@app.task
def link_error_task(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Link error executed")


@app.task
def link_task():
    print("Link executed")


def main():
    c1 = chain(error_task.si(), task1.si())
    head = group([c1])
    callback = callback_task.si().set(link=[link_task], link_error=[link_error_task.s()])

    chord(head, callback).delay()
```

I expect following things to happen:

1) Celery worker starts executing tasks in chain **c1**.

2) After reaching exception in **error_task** celery stops executing chain **c1**.

3) The error from chord **header** is propagated to the chord **callback**. As a result, **callback** execution will be marked as failed and finally **link_error** of the callback will be executed.

To execute this code I run following commands:

- Terminal 1:

  ```
  $ celery -A test worker --app=test:app --loglevel=info
  ```
- Terminal 2:

  ```
  $ python
  Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 29 2016, 14:05:02)
  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import test
  >>> test.main()
  ```

The celery output will be following:

```
[2016-07-14 21:39:36,186: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: test.error_task[b9e7d006-43f9-4e9d-8391-ada74fb3bc4e]
[2016-07-14 21:39:36,193: ERROR/MainProcess] Task test.error_task[b9e7d006-43f9-4e9d-8391-ada74fb3bc4e] raised unexpected: Exception('Mocked exception',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/test.py", line 11, in error_task
    raise Exception("Mocked exception")
Exception: Mocked exception
```

As we can see **link_error** was not executed. However, if we remove last task in **c1**, the program will work as expected:

```
    def main():
        c1 = chain(error_task.si()) # last task removed
        head = group([c1])
        callback = callback_task.si().set(link=[link_task], link_error=[link_error_task.s()])

        chord(head, callback).delay()
```

The output will be following:

```
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,177: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: test.error_task[96d5cb6c-b059-452a-b8cf-73e54f495976]
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,185: ERROR/Worker-4] Chord 'b3f57200-a52f-426f-9814-202576ae3538' raised: "Dependency 96d5cb6c-b059-452a-b8cf-73e54f495976 raised Exception('Mocked exception',)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 580, in on_chord_part_return
    ret = j(timeout=3.0, propagate=propagate)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 691, in join_native
    raise value
Exception: Mocked exception
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,207: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: test.link_error_task[c3c4408b-17fc-4efa-b502-c7cdf3862240]
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,209: WARNING/Worker-3] Link error executed
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,210: ERROR/MainProcess] Task test.error_task[96d5cb6c-b059-452a-b8cf-73e54f495976] raised unexpected: Exception('Mocked exception',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/private/tmp/test.py", line 11, in error_task
    raise Exception("Mocked exception")
Exception: Mocked exception
[2016-07-14 21:42:47,214: INFO/MainProcess] Task test.link_error_task[c3c4408b-17fc-4efa-b502-c7cdf3862240] succeeded in 0.00591249897843s: None
```

To conclude, the problem seems to be with the chain **c1**. If there is at least one task after the task, which triggers an error, the **link_error** of the **callback** will not be executed.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?